# Discord.py send Embed with random colour: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to reply with embeds, here is the code:
imports:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
```

```py
async def reminder():
  channel = client.get_channel(1043655467089535067)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="This is my embed", description="Its very cool", colour=discord.colour.random())
  await channel.send(embed)
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/inandoutbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 55, in on_ready
    await reminder()
  File "main.py", line 85, in reminder
    embed = discord.Embed(title="This is my embed", description="Its very cool", colour=discord.colour.random())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I gave up trying, i think i missing someting

Answer (score 1):

The error lies within `discord.colour.random`, with the lowercase *colour* beeing the `colour` module and `colour.random` pointing to the `random` module - which raises the error.

You need the uppercase `Colour` class, where random then is a function.

```
discord.Colour.random
```